How to explain the totally different results from subsample analysis and interaction analysis
I'm running a panel data regression.
The main independent variable A is a treatment indicator. There is also another variable B that can split the sample into two online and offline observations.
While running subsample analysis, the effects of A for online observation is not significant (col 5,6). The effect of A for offline observations is significantly negative (col 7,8).
However, while running the regression interacting B with A, the effect for online observations is significantly negative while the effect for offline observations is significantly positive (col 9,10).
Why would the results be like this?
I'm aware of the Simpson's paradox but I cannot seem to wrap my head around this situation.
Ps. I'm using two-way fixed-effect model.
Here is the screenshot of my results:


Welcome to CV. It is better not to post screenshots as they are hard to read. Even when I zoomed in, it was hard to tell what was going on. In your table, which variable is A, which is B and which is the interaction?

Sorry for the hard-to-read screenshot. To clarify, A is entry_qx. B is ctg_onlyonline.

Then the results make perfect sense. The interaction is telling you exactly what the subsample analysis did.

But my main confusion is that how come the coefficient of entry_qx is negative in col 7&8 (offline obs) but positive in col 9&10 (also offline obs, ctg_onlyonline=0)...?

See my comment.
However, in general, when you get puzzling results from an interaction, looking at predicted results can be very helpful. Here, with only two variables (but it looks like you have covariates0 and each dichotomous, I would output the predicted results for each of four combinations.
Aldo, looking at main effects when there is an interaction isn't a great idea because the whole point of an interaction is that the main effect of one variable is different at different levels of the other variable.
